# libcmtd.lib(exe_main.obj) error lnk2001 unresolved external symbol main

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors, libcmtd

I am getting this error as part of my VC C++ project.
libcmtd.lib(exe_main.obj) error lnk2001 unresolved external symbol main

It's simple Hello world project for now which I am trying to build in Release mode in x64. I am using MTd as runtime library.

Comment: And do you have a `main` function in your code? Can you please [edit] your question to include a copy-paste (as text) of your code?

Comment: Please provide more information about the configuration or a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use Unicode for this project? Look into the project properties. If you used Unicode the function should be "wmain" instead of "main", I believe. And also if you used the typed version for strings regarding Unicode you should use "_tmain".
The same rule applies to string operations, iostream etc. E.g. "_ftprint" instead of "fprint" etc.